# Can we understand overfitting from MAPE?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

So, we know that a significant difference between training and test errors might be the result of overfitting so here I have for a time series data:

`MAPE: 10.373` for training set and
 `MAPE: 23.821` for test set

Is it enough information to understand or detect overfitting? Or is it a really significant difference? What kind of techniques should I apply to investigate more?
Thank you

Comment: This question wold probably be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Ethan thank you! I will have a look but would be great if someone has a quick answer already!

Comment: Different accuracy measures will be more appropriate for different situations. https://otexts.com/fpp3/accuracy.html.  To the extent MAPE is a meaningful measure for this situation, my non-scientific impression is that is strongly suggestive of overfitting.